NIC context switch with PREEMPT-RT
In the communication (with UDP protocol) between a Ubuntu 20.04 PC, patched with PREEMPT-RT, and an external machine, the nominal behavior foresees an alternating packet exchange between the two entities.
However, sometimes it happens that 5 packets are received together by the same entity (the PC), thus not allowing a correct communication.
I hypothesized that the reason could be the Network Interface Controller (NIC) undergoing a context switch.
I assume that it is necessary to assign the highest priority to this process, or assign it to an isolated CPU, which needs to be separated from the scheduling system that the OS normally uses.
Has anyone ever encountered such a problem and found an effective solution?
I am engaged in a communication between a PC (with 8 cores) and a C4G controller of a Comau robot, but at some point the communication drops, not allowing operations to go on.
Analyzing the packet exchange between the PC and the controller with Wireshark, it was noted that: nominally, there should be an alternation between packets send by the C4G controller and those sent by the PC. Specifically, the packet exchange occurs every 2 milliseconds, i.e., the PC waits for a packet and after receiving it sends one to the controller. This is an example of nominal communication, where 10.2.12.150 is the C4G controller's IP and 10.2.12.149 PC's IP:



Timestamps
Difference between current and previous timestamps




11,134246
0.001901


11,134365
0.000119


11,136274
0.001909


11,136399
0.000125



complete table of nominal communication
However, at some point it happens that, after a time of about 10 milliseconds (5 communication cycles), the C4G controller sends 5 packets simultaneously (in fact, the difference between two timestamps is 0):



Timestamps
Difference between current and previous timestamps




31,708673
0.010566


31,708673
0


31,708673
0


31,708673
0


31,708673
0



complete table
Instead, using the same C4G controller, on another PREEMPT-RT patched PC (with 20 cores), this situation does not happen.
It was hypothesized that the C4G controller sends packets in the correct time, but the NIC does not raise the interrupt signal right away, because the NIC undergoes a context switch.

In order to understand if the problem is the high priority of the application process, I tried to do an execution without the real time kernel. This attempt has been successful: the communication went on for tens of minutes without any problem even starting other processes on the PC.
So I supposed that during the execution with the real time kernel, the system daemons are subject to context switching because their priority is equal (or lower) than that of other processes.

After this, another try has been made, this time on the real time kernel. To understand if the priority of our application thread is too high, I tried to change this priority and make it lower: specifically, the thread priority has been set at 1 which it is the lowest priority that enables the real time policies, but the communication between C4G controller and PC fell anyway. So, probably, there are other processes that have the same priority as the kernel daemons and that caused the context switch of the latest. How I can identify the NIC related kernel processes and raise their priority?
